# Confused with GoQuery

Tags: go, goquery

I'm making a bot that will store posts on Reddit that have more than 1000 upvotes. I intend to store the links and the urls.

I'm having trouble in finding a way to match the links/urls of the posts that have more than 1000 upvotes, I'm using the following GoQuery functions:

Getting the upvotes:

```
doc.Find(".score.unvoted").Each(func(i int, s *goquery.Selection) {

    voteValue, _ := strconv.Atoi(s.Text())

    greaterThan(voteValue)

    if strings.Contains(s.Text(), "k") || greaterThan(voteValue) {
        postUpvotes = append(postUpvotes, s.Text())
    }

    fmt.Println("UPVOTES SLICE", postUpvotes)
})
```

Getting the URL's:

```
doc.Find(".title.may-blank").Each(func(i int, s *goquery.Selection) {

        url, ok := s.Attr("href")

        if ok {
            link = url
            links = append(links, link)
            fmt.Println("LINKS SLICE -> ", links)
        }
    })
```

Getting the post title:

```
doc.Find(".title.title.may-blank").Each(func(i int, s *goquery.Selection) {

        fmt.Println("Titulo", s.Text())

        title = s.Text()
        titles = append(titles, title)

    })
```

The trouble is that, despite I can get the right amount of upvotes, some links and urls from posts are from posts that have less than 1000 upvotes, and I don't want that.

I've tried to replicate the way that I got the upvotes, but it doesn't works either.

Hope someone can help me or give me an insight, thanks in advance!

**If the post is too long, let me know and I'll create a gist.**

Comment: How does your `greaterThan()` function look like?

Comment: Not a solution for your question, but Reddit offers most of its data publicly as JSON, which may be easier to process: https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/8yg6ig/adding_json_onto_the_end_of_most_reddit_urls/

Comment: @Z.Kosanovic it receives an integer as a parameter, if the integer is >= 1000, it returns true, if it isn't, returns false.

Comment: @fstanis I didn't know that, I'm going to try using JSON, it'll probably be easier to manipulate the data. Thanks.